# Fixed point of a dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

What does a fixed point mean in a autonomous dynamical system, I mean I know the definition of it, but I keep hearing that if a dynamical system starts at a fixed point then it will remain there, why is this true.

Say $$ \frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,y) \\ \frac{dy}{dt} = g(x,y)$$

And suppose $(a,b)$ is a fixed point. 
Can someone show me why taking initial condition to be this fixed point then the system will remain at this fixed point, I see $\frac{dx}{dt}(0)= 0$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}(0) = 0$ but why must $x(t)=a$ and $y(t)=b$ at all times. I will be very grateful is someone were to clear this up for me.

Comment: Cauchy-Lipschitz.

Comment: @did: Picard-Lindelöf?

Comment: Yes can you please explain how to apply this here.

Comment: @Did On the name of the theorem: true that Cauchy and Lipschitz were the first to give formulations of the theorem, but without the modern view put forward by Picard and others (which allows one to discuss what we nowadays call a well-posed problem). Lindelöf's name appears because he noticed that Picard made a hypothesis (on the size of the neighborhood) that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Did wrote, the theorem of Chauchy-Lipschitz/Picard-Lindelöf (see below for a note) states for us that, if the functions $f$ and $g$ are uniformly Lipschitz-continuous, and we are given an inital condition $x(0)=x_0$, $y(0)=y_0$ then we have a unique solution $(x,y)$ satisfying the differential equations.

For a stable fixed point, the constant functions $(x,y) \equiv (a,b)$ do satisfy the initial conditions $x(0)=a$, $y(0)=b$ and the differential equation.

So if we do have **any** solution of the differential equation which satisfies $x(0)=a, y(0)=b$, then by uniqueness, it **must coincide** with the constant solution.

Note that the theorem in question is called Cauchy-Lipschitz in French and Picard–Lindelöf in English and German  and refer to the desired uniqueness result for an initial value problem $v'(t) = f(t,v(t))$, $v(t_0)=v_0$, where we need continuity of $f$ in the real variable $t$, and global Lipschitz continuity w.r.t. the second argument. Now in the most basic setting, the second argument is a real number as well, which is shown in the [english wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem). However, the way of proving it for the second argument being an element of $\mathbb R^n$ or even of some Banach space $E$ is exactly the same, which is shown in the [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_von_Picard-Lindel%C3%B6f) and [French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Cauchy-Lipschitz) wikipedia.

Comment: But isn't Picard lindelof just for one variable system here we have x and y and both are functions of t.

Comment: Thanks Roland this answers it perfectly!!!